# Ntlm code works on only Samsung devices

Tags: android, httpclient, ntlm

I am using NTLM authentication code at this url;
http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/ntlm.html

But it authenticates only on Samsung devices. When i try on Nexus 4, i got "Access is denied due to invalid credentials" error message from server. Even in same Android versions.

Is that possible?

I get httpclient object like this;

```
Registry<AuthSchemeProvider> authSchemeRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<AuthSchemeProvider>create()
            .register(AuthSchemes.NTLM, new JCIFSNTLMSchemeFactory())
            .register(AuthSchemes.BASIC, new BasicSchemeFactoryHC4())
            .register(AuthSchemes.DIGEST, new DigestSchemeFactoryHC4())
            .build();

CredentialsProvider cp = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
cp.setCredentials(new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), new NTCredentials(NTLM_USERNAME, NTLM_PASSWORD, "", ""));
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultAuthSchemeRegistry(authSchemeRegistry)
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(cp)
            .build();
```

Comment: share a part of the source where you do smth like "httpClient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why you have this bug, but if you need only NTML authentication, you could try use my code.

```
public class JsonRpcClient {

    private static final String HOST = "blabla.yourhostname.com";

    private final AbstractHttpClient httpClient;

    public JsonRpcClient(String username, String password) {
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new JCIFSNTLMSchemeFactory());
        httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(HOST, -1),
            new NTCredentials(username, password, "", ""));
    }

    ...

}
```

It work for me on nexus 4 and emulators.